# BirthDate and BirthDateRaw not set on user registration

Tags: c#, sqlite, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a form that handles user registration by sending data to the default route of `~/api/register`, but it doesn't work for BirthDate and neither for BirthDateRaw (mapped respectively as `DateTime?` and `string` in ServiceStack's UserAuth class). For both fields, the corresponding attribute in my Users table remains `NULL` (I'm using SQLite), and I can't fathom the reason why.

Here's a basic example of what my code looks like.

```
<form method="post" action="~/api/register">
    <label for="Input_BirthDate">Your birth date</label>
    <input type="date" id="BirthDate">

    <label for="Input_BirthDateRaw">Your birth date in raw text</label>
    <input type="text" id="BirthDateRaw">

    <label for="Input_Email">Your email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="Email">

    <label for="Input_Password">Your password</label>
    <input type="password" id="Password">

    <input type="submit" value="Create new user">
</form>
```

*Just to be clear, I'm not actually asking the user for their birth date in both formats but I've included them to show what I tried so far.* Also, please note that I have extended the default UserAuth class by just adding a couple of additional properties, but **I'm using the default registration service.**

If I pass the form to a JS function for submitting, a quick `console.log()` shows no anomalies in the inputs, so the issue must lie in the server side of things; can someone provide any bit of insight on the matter?

On the other hand, if I wanted to place a breakpoint to clearly see in the debugger what's going on behind the scenes and what ServiceStack is doing with the data once it reaches the server, which classes should I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only update the properties on the [Register DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/ec7ae4af09034a0dd5d54f643c3d7cef1f7b887b/src/ServiceStack.Client/AuthDtos.cs#L65-L78):

```
public class Register : IPost, IReturn<RegisterResponse>, IMeta
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public bool? AutoLogin { get; set; }
    public string Continue { get; set; }
    public string ErrorView { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Meta { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to capture more information you'll need to either add a custom [OnRegistered() AuthEvent](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events) to populate additional Inputs from the `IRequest` and update it in the AuthRepository, e.g:

```
public class CustomUserAuth : AuthUserSession
{
    public override void OnRegistered(IRequest req, IAuthSession session, 
        IServiceBase authService)
    {
        var authRepo = HostContext.AppHost.GetAuthRepository(req);
        using (authRepo as IDisposable)
        {
            var userAuth = (AppUser)authRepo.GetUserAuth(session.UserAuthId);
            userAuth.BirthDateRaw = request.FormData["BirthDateRaw"];
            authRepo.SaveUserAuth(userAuth);
        }
    }
}
```

Or have it call your own Service (e.g. after registration), or use your own [custom Register Service](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/RegisterService.cs) with a custom Register DTO that contains all the properties you want to be able to set.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but can you also tell me the reason behind the cast to `AppUser`? Without it, `var userAuth` is of type `IUserAuth` and the code runs just fine. Also if I use "AppUser" literally it's not correct, so I guess it must be the type of the user session or something akin to it, right?

Comment: @rdxdk It's [an example for extending the UserAuth table](https://docs.servicestack.net/mix-tool#encapsulated-features), you'd need to cast it to whatever Custom UserAuth table you're using in your Auth Repository generic constructor. If you're not using a Custom Table you don't need to cast it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks again.